# Create a new object if current field is null in database

Tags: java, jpa, playframework

I have a database model class `Project`, and it has two embedded object fields:

```
@Embedded
public ContacterInfo contacter = new ContacterInfo();

@Embedded
public CompanyInfo company = new CompanyInfo();
```

'cause I don't want to check `is null` every time I use `company` and `contacter`, so I decided to create them anyway.

What I expected is, when there's nothing for `contacter` in database, Java would create a new `ContacterInfo` for me, and then I can just use it for new data. But in fact, I found `contacter` still could be set to `null`. I suspect that JPA load `null` from database and override my new create object with it.

How can I fix this ?

Comment: You should put the `contacter = new ContacterInfo();` inside the setter of your `contacter` if the `ContacterInfo` is null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the *JPA Entity listeners* ([ObjectDB has a good explication](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/event)). By example:

```
@PostLoad 
void onPostLoad() {
   if (contacter == null) {
      contacter = new ContacterInfo();
   }
   if (company == null) {
      company = new CompanyInfo();
   }
}
```

Every time JPA load an instance of current entity, `onPostLoad` will be called.

Good luck!